# Prevent caching for info div after set cookie successful

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cookies

I made my own "accept cookie" info on my page. I'm using a variable which get echoed in footer. If the cookie for this info is set, the variable get ' '; else it gets the div with the text.

I'm using jQuery to hide and set cookie for div like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".warning_close").click(function(){
       event.preventDefault();          
        $(".warning").animate({ height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' }, 'fast');   
        Cookies.set('cookie_alert', '1', { expires: 365, path: '/' });
    });
});
```

PHP code:

```
function warntext($post_cookie, $name_cookie, $text_cookie)
{

        if(isset($_POST[$post_cookie]) && !isset($_SESSION[$name_cookie])){
            setcookie($name_cookie, '1', strtotime( '+365 days' ), '/');
            return $var_cookie='';
        }
        if(isset($_COOKIE[$name_cookie]))
        {
            return $var_cookie='';
        } else {
            return $var_cookie='<div class="warning"><div><span>'.$text_cookie.'</span></div><div class="warningwrapper"><form class="warning_form" action="" name="warning" method="post"><button type="submit" name="'.$post_cookie.'" class="warning_close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></form></div></div>';
        }
    }
```

If JavaScript is enabled the server doesn't refresh on click of the close button and the cookie get set via jQuery successful, as fallback because event.preventDefault();  gets ignored, the cookie is set through PHP.

**But the problem is** if JavaScript is enabled, because of no refresh the div stay cached and a hard reload is necessary. Like that every time the user come back to that page he has to close the info again...

How can I fix this?

**Solution:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".warning_close").click(function(){   
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $(".warning").animate({ height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' }, 'fast');   
        Cookies.set('cookie_alert', '1', { expires: 365, path: '/' });
    });
    if (Cookies.get('cookie_alert')) {
        $( ".warning" ).addClass( "displaynoo" );
    }
});
```

Now only if js is enabled I'm adding display:none; to the div, else if disabled the PHP function does the job.

Comment: The way I would do this is: By default the info message is always there but hidden. When Javascript is enabled, and detects the cookie has not yet been set, it shows the info message. When the user accepts cookies the cookie is set. When the cookie is not set, no other cookies can be stored. (most websites ignore this last rule!)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thanks, this is a good idea but how can i show the div if javascript is disabled. Edit: won't import a css file with single css line.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware ahh sorry i understood now, it's working perfect. Thanks.